# How do you find more documentation about queries, services, plugins, etc?

Tags: plugin-development, queries, documentation

So I've been having so much trouble finding adequate examples of how to do things when writing a plugin. How do you find more?  (see below for my own answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the little triangle! It gives nice examples.  [image]